# Since all user threads are mapped to kernel threads , then user threads are running in kernal mode?

Tags: linux, multithreading, operating-system, kernel

I know this is not true. But why? Am I'm confusing kernel threads and kernel mode?

Comment: The problem with the above statement is, that's not true!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, when you perform a system call. But that's not what the term really means.

"Kernel threads" refers to the fact that the kernel itself recognizes each thread as being separate. This means that they each have a corresponding data structure in the kernel, and the kernel can treat them individually, such as by scheduling them separately. The mode the thread is running in has nothing to do with it since it is just the concept of the thread in the kernel.

"User threads" are implemented in user space. The kernel has no idea that there are multiple threads in the process, and so cannot treat them individually. The kernel just sees the main thread, and might not separate it from the process at all.

Comment: Thanks. but let me get this straight. kernel threads execute both kernel mode/user mode code. Is that right?

Comment: @gawicks Yes. A few might only run in the kernel, but most of them will be running in user mode most of the time and occasionally kernel mode.